# is it possible to replace the metal on the bottom of a PCB?

Tags: pcb, repair, through-hole

[image]I attempted to drill three holes slightly bigger on a circuit board. As soon as I touched the board with the drill, the metal that you solder contacts to separated from the board. I want to know if there is a way to repair the board.
[image: Underside of my PCB]

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? If you drilled out the holes you broke contact between those bottom-layer pads and any inner or top-layer traces anyway. If you just want to mechanically secure the part to the board, a few drops of epoxy should do.

Comment: There are NO "wire traces" evident in your photo.  Even if the original pads were still there, they don't appear to connect to ANYTHING on that side of the board. If you need to repair the board and connect the component to the PC board traces, you will need to do it from the OTHER side.  By now, I expect that you have learned the hard lesson that you cannot expect to "drill out" component holes or pads on a PC board.

Comment: Summing up what the others are saying, we can't tell whether the board will work correctly because we don't know whether you broke any internal conductive pathways or whether there are any pads on the other side of the board you could use for soldering.

Comment: It looks like you need to make the track repairs on the other side of the board, or on internal layers if it's a multilayer board. Both are possible, but for internal layers you need to identify an accessible via nearby, or another pin on the same net. And beware of layer crossings at that pin - you may need to add more than one wire.

Comment: So, do you still have pads on top, but not on bottom? If so, just try soldering the part on the top only and see if the circuit works. If the only trace connection is on the top layer, that will probably work. In future, if you need to enlarge holes on a PCB, use a "pin vice" to hold the drill bit, and bore it out by hand (no drill). This will normally disconnect the pins from internal layers, but sometimes that may be what you are trying to do, or there may not be any internal connections in the first place. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what is damaged and what do you want to fix.
But most likely you cut one trace. In that case you can fix it by bit of wire. Just carefully scratch away solder mask on both ends of that trace and solder wire on that place. This is the way you can fix broken traces.

Comment: The metal let go of the silicon when i attempted to drill through the board. Would the wire trace be microscopic?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "microscopic". Look at your image. You have some traces on the right side (2 traces are going from top to bottom) and that is the width of your traces.

Comment: How many layers does your board have? Is it 2-layers PCB? Or there are some inner layers?

Comment: I think there are only two layers, the top and the bottom. It does not appear to touch any traces on the bottom.